# Does Sitecore express migration tool 3.1 support to upgrade from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.3

Tags: upgrade, express-migration-tool

I could see that sitecore express migration tool supports to migrate from previous old versions to sitecore 9 initial version. If i have to upgrade to sitecore 9.3, what steps need to follow?

If anyone has done these kind of migrations, your inputs will be really useful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the sitecore knowledge base
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0400952#notes it is stated:

`[2] At the moment, the Express Migration Tool is not compatible with Sitecore XP 9.1 and later versions.`

However if you have sitecore 8.1 or 8.2 you do not need the migration tool as it is only required for versions 8.0 or below. You can just use the sitecore update package directly for your content.

Comment: thanks Cristi, actually it's my first upgrade. would be helpful if you can share any links or details to use sitecore update package directly for the content.

Comment: It will depend on your upgrade scenario, you can take a look at two approaches described https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24144/how-to-do-a-data-migration-from-8-2-to-9-3. Last time I have just setup a fresh 9.3 instance and installed the page content from 8.2 to 9.3 through sitecore packages, the rest of the items (templates/renderings/settings) being installed through unicorn.

Comment: There are upgrade script you can run against the database. Take a backup of the 8.2 db, run  the upgrade scripts against it,  The upgrade scripts can be found on the 9.3 download page, along with the rest of the upgrade materials.

Comment: Other approach:• Installed a new Sitecore 9.3
• Synced templates from the solution to the new instance via Unicorn or TDS
• Updated all project dependencies with Sitecore 9.3 and its other affected dependencies including configuration
• Fix breaking changes and adjust deprecated approaches in the code
• Package content items from the old site and install them in the new instance
• Publish, rebuild indexes

Comment: Thanks @AmitKumar for your approach.. Can we do Synced content items as well like templates Instead of package content items from old site since we are using bucket items ,custom rule items, etc..

Comment: Yes. You can except if you have modified any OOTB templates

Comment: For any serialized items you can just run unicorn sync on the fresh 9.3 instance and it will work.