# Sitecore 8.2 to 9.3 Upgrade the databases approach

Tags: upgrade, migration

We are planning to upgrade from Sitecore 8.2 update 2 to 9.3. Customer suggests to follow DB upgrade approach. I have followed the below steps to upgrade the databases as per sitecore upgrade approach doc but nothing changed in Sitecore interfaces after run the below scripts and also didn't get any error. Do i need to follow any other steps to upgrade the databases apart from the 2 scripts

***To upgrade the databases:***

1. Extracted the database upgrade scripts from the Database Upgrade Script.zip file
2. Executed the below script individually in top of sitecore 8.2 core database, master database and web database
   **CMS_core_master_web8x.sql**
3. Executed the below script in top of Sitecore 8.2 core database
   **CMS_core.sql**

I would like to know anyone has worked on a similar migration. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed the update packages yet? Normally the interface is changed via files.

Comment: @Kanniyappan only upgrading database will not change UI, you need to Install the Sitecore Update Installation Wizard 4.0.1 rev. 00153 for 8.x9.0.zip package.

Comment: Also, how you are planning to upgrade the solution as well? I mean app_configs, bin, code etc?

Comment: @Kanniyappan in that case no, see my second approach, that is what you are doing right now.

Answer (score 8):

You need to follow the upgrade guide that you can download from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/93/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_93_Initial_Release.aspx

Also after doing a database upgrade, you need to follow **Install the Upgrade package** then **Configure Sitecore** and so on to have the upgraded version 9.3.

You need to download below from the above url.

[image]

Also, another approach is by following [How to do a data migration from 8.2 to 9.3](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24144/how-to-do-a-data-migration-from-8-2-to-9-3-)

1. Set up a blank version of your starting environment (8.2 for you) and attach your core/master databases. In your case, since you have custom tables in the core db, you might want to back those up and then drop them before the upgrade. I'd also consider just running them out of a separate database, but I don't know your specifics with them.
2. Run the upgrade from 8.2 to 9.3; this will upgrade your databases as well.
3. Install a clean 9.3 environment, replace the core/master databases there with the upgraded ones.
4. Upgrade your code, etc, and hook everything up to your new environment.